# Magento Add Country Attribute to Customer Address Entity

Tags: magento

I need to add new fields like street,country in the account registration page.How do I add another country field without conflicting existing one.I tried the following,but the selected country doesn't show up in admin.

```
<div class="field">
<label for="country2" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country 2') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<?php
$_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadData()->toOptionArray(false) ?>
<?php if (count($_countries) > 0): ?>
    <select name='trading2_country' id='trading2_country'>
        <option value=''>– Please Select –</option>
        <?php foreach($_countries as $_country): ?>
            <option value='<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>'><?php echo $_country['label'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```